# Styling issues on primeNG Dropdown control

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have used the grouped dropdown component from PrimeNG, I want the dropdown's

**First section** to have a toggle button.
**Second section** to have options which would work as a select component works.

I need suggestions on which component could be used as a base component to create a similar functionality. Like shown in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMHGx.jpg

I was able to use this component (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown) to style the dropdown to look like the wanted component, missing the toggle button section, But when the toggle button is added in to the dropdown template, and the toggle button is clicked the dropdown closes.

*I just want suggestions on the component shown in the image, not looking for code.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-zorro for a similar output.
Here is the link of documentation.
https://ng.ant.design/docs/introduce/en

Also, I have created a sample similar to the question in Stackblitz

You can check it here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-dropdown-template-using-ngzorro